# angular 2 dynamic template created from user-defined templates

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-template

Is it possible to have user-defined templates say based on user-defined parameters from the server - and then have a component take them in as its template?

These templates are user-specific and not available during the build of the angular app.

I was thinking of loading this templates up-front before the entire angular app loads but not clear on how to achieve this using angular-cli.

any ideas?

thanks